# How to Add Custom Option in MS Word File Menu by Office Addin using manifest.xml

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, ribbonx

How can we add a custom option in "File Menu/Tab" by custom "Office Addin"?

I can find how to add "Control" in an office tab using "ExtensionPoint". But I am unable to find how can we add a custom option in "File Menu". Following are the documentation links I have gone through.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/officetab

image 1: [image: File Menu Screenshot]

image 2: [image: Customized File menu By Worldox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Backstage UI can't be customized with web add-ins. See [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) for more information about possible customizations.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

FYI these customizations are possible using COM add-ins, so you may also consider creating a VSTO based add-in instead, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20Outlook%20project%20in%20Visual%20Studio&text=In%20the%20templates%20pane%2C%20expand,Outlook%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project.).

Comment: They may also be done using a template Add-In. See https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html and http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0470191112/balancecheckbookA/

Comment: There only add-ins were mentioned, macro-enabled documents is another story.

Comment: Those are templates that can be used as Add-Ins by placing them in a Word Startup Folder. They are called template add-ins. My pages: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global http://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm

Comment: It is not designed for distributing changes on multiple machines.

Comment: Yes. It is. It is deployed through distribution to each computer's startup folder. It can be shortcut to a network location.

Comment: Ribbon customizations don't require any additional steps with add-ins for deployment.